# Django __iregex Returns Empty Response

Tags: python, mysql, regex, django

I have an `Article` model that takes in articles from users. These articles can have *#hashtags* in them like we have in twitter. I have these hashtags converted to links that users can click to load all articles that have the clicked hashtags in them.

If I have these articles saved in `Article` model:

```
1.  'For the love of learning: why do we give #Exam?'
2.  'Articles containing #Examination should not come up when exam is clicked'
3.  'This is just an #example post'
```

I tried using Django's `__icontains` filter

```
def hash_tags(request, hash_tag):
    hash_tag = '#' + hash_tag
    articles = Articles.objects.filter(content__icontains=hash_tag)
    articles = list(articles)
    return HttpResponse(articles)
```

but if user clicks on `#exam` the three articles are returned instead of the first one.

I can add space to '#exam' to become '#exam ' and it will work out fine but I want to be able to do it with regex.

I have tried:

```
articles = Articles.objects.filter(content__iregex=r"\b{0}\b".format(hash_tag))
```

but I get empty response.

How do I do this correctly to have it work? I am using Django 1.6 and MySQL at backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this finally.

```
articles = Articles.objects.filter(content__iregex=r"^[^.]*{0}*[[:>:]]".format(hash_tag))
```

And that's it!

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to remove the first `\b` because there isn't a word boudary exists between `#` and the space. ie, if the value of `hash_tag` variable is `#exam`, `r"\b{0}\b"` will produce the regex `\b#exam\b`. And this won't match `#exam` present next to the space, since there isn't a word boundary exists between space and `#`, so it would fail. `#` and space are non-word characters. `\b` matches between a word character and a non-word character.

```
content__iregex=r"{0}\b".format(hash_tag)
```

Add a case-insensitive modifier if necessary.

```
content__iregex=r"(?i){0}\b".format(hash_tag)
```

Comment: I have just tried this but it returns this error from the backend `OperationalError at /mysite/get_hashtags/Exam/
(1139, "Erreur 'repetition-operator operand invalid' provenant de regexp")`

Comment: did you try this `content__iregex=r"{0}\b".format(hash_tag)` ?

Comment: I just did. `content__iregex=r"{0}\b".format(hash_tag)` returns empty response while `content__iregex=r"(?i){0}\b".format(hash_tag)` returns the error I reported.

Comment: What's the value of hash_tag variable?

Comment: `#Examination` and when it returns that error it highlight `posts = list(posts)` in the **Traceback**.

Comment: see https://regex101.com/r/bO4zV5/3 it works here. But don't why it fails to match.

Comment: Can the field type affect the regex search? Content is `CharField`.